# Read architecture information from object file

Tags: c, linux

I wanted to read the architecture information about object(.so) files example x86, x86_64, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips etc from the file and display these information. I know I can use "file" or other Linux commands to get this info, But I wanted to use the kernel structure to get above values.

I went through the ELF header file but not getting much help.

Can someone please suggest how to proceed for this?

Comment: What do you mean with "kernel structure"?

Comment: In elf header file I saw Elf32_Half    e_machine; which provides these architecture info. Is it possible to get through that. I could not get any examples on how to get the e_machine info. Please refer http://www.ouah.org/RevEng/x430.htm.

Comment: Take a look at `readelf`, it's open source and supplied with most Linux distributions.

Comment: Note: *.so files are dynamic libraries, not necessarily 'elf' files

Comment: the format of a 'elf' file is not a 'kernel structure' but rather a 'elf' file structure.  Note: not all structs are present in a 'elf' file and some structs may be present multiple times.  If you follow the link given in the above link to the actual format: <http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf> you will find the details of how the 'elf' file is formatted.  It is actually quite easy to extract the first header block, which contains the e_machine field and contains a list of the possible values and their meanings for that field.

Comment: @user3629249 is there any other way to get the architecture information apart from the ELF?

Comment: Perhaps in your code:  open the elf file with mode 'rb', read the file into an instance of the struct for the header in the elf file.  examine the e_machine field of that struct.

Answer (score 0):

A elf binary contains a elf-header at the beginning of the file. You can read this header by any elf-reader program, and here I will give you the example for     readelf

```
readelf -h <binaryFile>
```

For more information, you could read the ELF Format Specification to learn about how elf binaries are loaded & executed.